# How do I update a value in a dataframe in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update a rating row by row. I have one dataframe of players, that all start with the same rating. For each match, I want the rating to change. Another dataframe contains results of each match.

```
import pandas as pd 

gamesdata = [['paul','tom'],['paul','lisa'],['tom','paul'],['lisa','tom'],['paul','lisa'],['lisa','tom'],['paul','tom']] 

games = pd.DataFrame(gamesdata, columns = ['Winner', 'Looser']) 

playersdata= ['lisa','paul','tom']

players = pd.DataFrame(playersdata, columns = ['Name']) 

mean_elo = 1000
elo_width = 400
k_factor = 64

players['elo'] = mean_elo

def update_elo(winner_elo, loser_elo):
    expected_win = expected_result(winner_elo, loser_elo)
    change_in_elo = k_factor * (1-expected_win)
    winner_elo += change_in_elo
    loser_elo -= change_in_elo
    return winner_elo, loser_elo

def expected_result(elo_a, elo_b):
    expect_a = 1.0/(1+10**((elo_b - elo_a)/elo_width))
    return expect_a

for index, row in games.iterrows():
    winnername = row['Winner']    
    losername = row['Looser']    
    web = players['elo'].loc[players['Name'] == winnername].values[0]
    wIndex = players.loc[players['Name'] == winnername]
    #I want to return just the index, so I can update the value
    print(wIndex)

    leb = players['elo'].loc[players['Name'] == losername].values[0]
    print('Winner Elo before: ' + str(web))
    winner_elo, looser_elo = update_elo(web, leb)
    print('Winner Elo after: ' + str(winner_elo))
    #here I want to update value
    #players.at[wIndex,'elo']=winner_elo
```

I am trying to update the value in the players table using

```
players.at[wIndex,'elo']=winner_elo
```

but i struggle to get the index with this code:

```
wIndex = players.loc[players['Name'] == winnername]
```

Comment: So, your problem is: how to get the index of the row where `players['Name'] == winnername` ?

Comment: Yes it was, but I figured it out - using .index.values

Comment: In the future, please think about how to create a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - after all, if your entire problem was in that line, you don't have to share the entire code of your game, it just makes it less clear what the question is.

Comment: Sorry about that, will be more minimalist next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a sollution:

```
 wIndex = players.loc[players['Name'] == winnername].index.values
```

Can't believe i missed that

Comment: In this case, mark your question as accepted, so that others will know that the question is closed

Comment: I am not allowed to accept my answer yet, I am afraid